# What is a good substitute for matlabFunction?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, numerical-integration, game-theory

I wrote a small program in MATLAB to compute the Shapley value 
using the multi-linear extension of a TU game. However, I run 
into trouble with the Symbolic Math Toolbox of MATLAB. In 
the program I have to integrate a set of functions to get the 
Shapley value. However, inside a MATLAB program I cannot use 
the int() command

```
Error using sym/subsindex (line 663) Ivalid indexing or function definition. When defining a function, ensure that the body of the function is a SYM object. When indexing, the input must be numeric, logical or ':'.

Error in ShapleyValueML (line 65)shv(jj)=int(dfy,0,1)
```

as a consequence I have to use integral() instead. In this case, I 
need to transcribe the set of expressions into MATLAB function handle 
with matlabFunction(). However, on all Linux machines (MATLAB R2014a) on 
which I have access this command does not work (see the discussion below). 
As a workaround, the MATLAB program returns the set of functions 
into the current workspace, there the Shapley value can be computed 
using the int() command.

To make the discussion more concrete, let us consider this small 
MATLAB program first.

```
function [shv,F,dfm]=ShapleyValueML(v)

N=length(v);
[~, n]=log2(N);
S=1:N;
int=0:-1:1-n; 
mat=(rem(floor(S(:)*pow2(int)),2)==1);
cmat=(rem(floor(S(:)*pow2(int)),2)==0);
x=sym('x',[1 n]);
mx=1-x;
y = sym('y');
vy=ones(1,n)*y;
F=0;
shv=zeros(1,n);
dfm=cell(1,n);

for ss=1:N
    pd1=x(mat(ss,:));
    pd2=mx(cmat(ss,:));
    pd=prod(pd1)*prod(pd2)*v(ss);
    F=pd+F;
end
F=expand(F);

 for jj=1:n
     dF=diff(F,x(jj));
     dfy=subs(dF,x,vy);
%% Does not work!! MATLAB bug??? 
%  mf=matlabFunction(dfy);
%  shv(jj)=integral(mf,0,1);
%%
%% The best would be to use:
%%
%   shv(jj)=int(dfy,0,1)
%% but it cannot be used inside a program.
 dfm{jj}=dfy;
 end

end
```

The commented parts are the parts that do not work inside 
the program, but are needed to compute the Shapley value 
with that program, which is its purpose. I tested this program 
up to 12 players, and I was able to successfully calculate the 
Shapley value by a two step procedure. Hence, the above program 
specifies correctly the considered problem. To get a better 
understanding of this two step procedure and of the functionality 
of the above program, let us focus on a three person game. 
The values of the coalitions are given by the following data array

```
>> v = [0,0,90,0,100,120,220];
```

Notice that coalitions are ordered in accordance with their unique 
integer representations. The game is defined, we can now evaluate 
the multi-linear extension and the set of partial derivatives with 
the above program, but not the Shapley value.

```
>> [shv,F,dfm]=ShapleyValueML(v);
```

Integration of the set of partial derivatives runs over the diagonal 
of the unit-cube, but then we can set the variables from [x1,x2,x3] 
to [y,y,y], and integration runs from 0 to 1.

```
>> for k=1:3, shv(k)=int(dfm{k},0,1);end;
```

The solution of the integration is the Shapley value given by:

```
>> shv

shv =

    65    75    80
```

Checking that this is indeed the Shapley value can be accomplished 
with a potential function approach implemented in

```
>> sh_v=ShapleyValue(v)

sh_v =

     65    75    80
```

that ships with my MATLAB Game Theory Toolbox MatTuGames from

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35933-mattugames

Instead of integrating with int() one can also use integral(), 
but then the contents like

```
>> dfm{1}

ans =

    - 90*y^2 + 190*y
```

must be rewritten with matlabFunction() into a function handle. As I 
have mentioned above this does not work under Linux 
(MATLAB R2013a,R2013b,R2014a). To see this let us try to reproduce 
the example

```
>> syms x y
>> r = sqrt(x^2 + y^2);
```

from the documentation at the URL:

http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/symbolic/generate-matlab-functions.html?searchHighlight=matlabFunction

This should give

```
ht = 
@(x,y)tanh(sqrt(x.^2+y.^2))
```

but I get

```
>> ht = matlabFunction(tanh(r))
   Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

   Error in vectorize (line 15)
    c = cells{i};

   Error in sym/matlabFunction>mup2mat (line 319)
   res = vectorize(res(2:end-1)); % remove quotes

   Error in sym/matlabFunction>mup2matcell (line 304)
    r = mup2mat(c{1});

   Error in sym/matlabFunction (line 123)
   body = mup2matcell(funs);
```

Here comes now my question: Exists there an alternative procedure to 
get from

```
>> dfm{1}

ans =

  - 90*y^2 + 190*y
```

a function handle

```
>> df=@(y) (- 90.*y.^2 + 190.*y)

 df = 

    @(y)(-90.*y.^2+190.*y)
```

to integrate it by

```
>> integral(df,0,1)

ans =

   65
```

Or to put it differently. Is there an alternative method available to 
change multiplication * to element-wise multiplication .*, and the 
power operation ^ to element-wise power.^?

Of course, any suggestions of improvement for the above MATLAB program 
are highly appreciated.

---

Comment: @Amro Thanks a lot. You are right!! I was blind not to see this failure. Nevertheless,it is a pity that MATLAB does not display a warning like Mathematica when a variable/function is shadowed by a builtin function.

Comment: yeah, that error message was a bit cryptic.. I had to step through the debugger and inspect the call stack to figure out what was going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know what the problem is; Towards the beginning of `ShapleyValueML` function, you have a variable named `int` which shadows the builtin [integration function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int.html):

```
...

int=0:-1:1-n;    %# <-- problem!

...

shv(jj)=int(dfy,0,1)

...
```

That explains the error coming from [`sym/subsindex`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsindex.html), you were using a symbolic object as an index into the numeric array `int`.

Change the variable name to something else, and the commented code runs fine (the symbolic integration)! Simple as that :)